# Filter list of dataframe according to the mean of one column in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, filter

I am trying to filter a list of dataframes depending on the mean value of one of their columns. If taking the following example:

```
# creating df1
df1 <- as_tibble(mtcars)

# creating df2
df2 <- as_tibble(iris)

# creating list of df (df_list)
df_list <- list(mtcars,iris)

# Checking the structure of the list
str(df_list)
List of 2
 $ : tibble [32 × 11] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
  ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
  ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
  ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
  ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
  ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
  ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
  ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
  ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
 $ : tibble [150 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ Sepal.Length: num [1:150] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
  ..$ Sepal.Width : num [1:150] 3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
  ..$ Petal.Length: num [1:150] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
  ..$ Petal.Width : num [1:150] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
  ..$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

I would like to obtain the means of the **3rd** column for each df (`disp` and `Petal.Lenght` in this example), and then I would like to keep only the df for which the means of these columns are > 10.

I have tried the following approach:

1. I created a function that returns a logical value depending on the calcualted mean:

   ```
   mean_logical <- function(column_mean) {
     column_mean_logical <- if_else(mean(column_mean) > 10, TRUE, FALSE)
     return(column_mean_logical)
   }
   ```
2. Then, I wanted to use keep from `{purrr}` and apply my function (`mean_logical`) to filter the df with a mean in the third column < 10. However I am struggling on how to instruct to check the third column of each df in my list.

Of note, the only way I found to "access" the third column of each df in a list is by using the following:

```
lapply(df_list, "[", 3)
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Filter` from `base`

```r
Filter(\(x) mean(x[[3]]) > 10, df_list)
```

or `keep` from `purrr`:

```r
purrr::keep(df_list, \(x) mean(x[[3]]) > 10)
```

with an anonymous predicate function.

Comment: That's perfect thank you very much!
Do I understand correctly that the "\(x)" allows iterating into each dataframe from the list?

Answer (score 3):

An approach using `subset` or indexing with `[`

```
subset(df_list, sapply(df_list, function(x) mean(x[,3]) > 10))
```

```
df_list[sapply(df_list, function(x) mean(x[,3]) > 10)]
```

Since **R 4.1.0** you can shorten `function(x)` with `\(x)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `map`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df_list %>%
  map(~ .x %>% filter(mean(.[,3]) > 10))
```

```
[[1]]
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

[[2]]
[1] Sepal.Length Sepal.Width  Petal.Length Petal.Width  Species     
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thanks this almost works as I would like to erase the whole dataframe iris from the list not just return a 0 rows dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `discard`

```
library(purrr)
discard(df_list, ~  mean(.x[[3]]) <= 10)
```